# How to validate email and minimum length validations

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, bootstrap-4

I want to validate  email input  which has the correct format and minimum length validations for first name and password by using only bootstrap .

Here I have done required field validations for the inputs but I don't know how to add email and minimum length validations.

Reference :http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/?#validation

HTML

```
 <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" minlength="4" id="validationCustom01" placeholder="First name" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              * First name is required
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="validationCustom02">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationCustom02" placeholder="Last name" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              * Last name is required
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              * Email is required
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-6">
            <label for="validationCustom03">Password</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" minlength="5" id="validationCustom03" placeholder="Password" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              * Password is required
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: read the docs. they even explain how to validate an email.

Answer (score 1):

you must use JS validation (and server side validation also).
HTML validation easily editable in all browsers.
In HTML you can use pattern in HTML5 like `<input pattern=".{8,20}">`
this will be check length from 8 char to 20.

Answer (score 0):

You can only add a validation *form-controls* class in bootstrap if it's empty or not.

Manipulating it on **JavaScript** will help you with this.

> A quick snippet for you to limit the number of characters in a span / div etc by a particular value. This function also includes a slightly neater … at the cutoff point:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(function(){
  $(".your-div").each(function(i){
    len=$(this).text().length;
    if(len>80)
    {
      $(this).text($(this).text().substr(0,80)+'...');
    }
  });
});
// ]]></script>
```

Reference: [Limit number of Characters in Div with jQuery or CSS](https://slickmedia.co.uk/blog/glenns-blog/limit-number-of-characters-in-div-jquery-css/)